# Cannot connect video filter to audio input

Tags: ffmpeg

When I run this command on FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i tonyboi.avi -filter "minterpolate='fps=60'" tony.mp4
```

I get this log:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, avi, from 'tonyboi.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:26.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1494 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1353 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
File 'tony.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Cannot connect video filter to audio input
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
```

Even though I am not using a audio format, it says I am.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the option `-filter`, you should attach the correct stream specifiers, in this case, `-filter:v`

```
ffmpeg -i tonyboi.avi -filter:v "minterpolate='fps=60'" tony.mp4
```